# difficulty with mysql join (nulls not showing)

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

So I have 6 tables all with 2 columns.  3 have the data I'm using and the other 3 just specify how they are related.

So with this example data:

```
central_item

id   name
-----------------
1    Chicken
2    Shrimp


cooking_method

id   name
-----------------
1    Bake
2    Fry


style

id   name
-----------------
1    Casserole
2    Pie


central_item_cooking_method

central_item  cooking_method
------------------------------
1             1
1             2
2             1
2             2


central_item_style

central_item  style
------------------------------
1             1
1             2
2             1


cooking_method_style

cooking_method  style
------------------------------
1               1
2               2
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
central_item_name  style_name  cooking_method_name
----------------------------------------------------
Chicken            null        Bake
Chicken            null        Fry
Chicken            Casserole   null
Chicken            Casserole   Bake
Chicken            Pie         null
Chicken            Pie         Bake
Shrimp             null        Bake
Shrimp             null        Fry
Shrimp             Casserole   null
Shrimp             Casserole   Bake
```

This is the query I've been trying.  The comments explain what each part is supposed to do.  When I run it the query is missing a lot of results where I would expect to see just 1 column null.

```
SELECT
#name these something better so they don't all get returned as just 'name'
central_item.name as `central_item_name`, style.name as `style_name`, cooking_method.name as `cooking_method_name`
#we need a central item no matter what so start here
FROM central_item
#get styles for items (optional)
LEFT JOIN central_item_style ON central_item_style.style = central_item.id OR central_item_style.style IS NULL
#get names for any matching styles
LEFT JOIN style ON style.id = central_item_style.style OR style.id IS NULL
#get cooking methods for items (optional)
LEFT JOIN central_item_cooking_method ON central_item_cooking_method.central_item = central_item.id OR central_item_cooking_method.central_item IS NULL
#get names for cooking methods
LEFT JOIN cooking_method ON cooking_method.id = central_item_cooking_method.cooking_method OR cooking_method.id IS NULL
#for the matching item cooking methods check which styles also match the cooking method.  For item styles check for matching cooking methods.
LEFT JOIN cooking_method_style ON cooking_method_style.style = central_item_style.style OR cooking_method_style.cooking_method = central_item_cooking_method.cooking_method

WHERE
#make sure we have at least one of these
(style.id IS NOT NULL OR cooking_method.id IS NOT NULL) AND
#cooking method or style can be null but we have both they need to be compatible with each other
(cooking_method.id IS NULL OR central_item_style.style = cooking_method_style.style) AND
(style.id IS NULL OR central_item_cooking_method.cooking_method = cooking_method_style.cooking_method)

#Remove duplicates
GROUP BY central_item.name, style.name, cooking_method.name
ORDER BY central_item.name, style.name, cooking_method.name
```

Comment: This IS a rubbish example. Who fries pasta?

Comment: There.  I changed it to shrimp.  The rest still makes sense.

Comment: Good. An item is a bit like an ingredient, isn't it?

Comment: Are you sure that that's the right result set?

Comment: check out my answer.  This is the correct result set.  For example you can have baked chicken.  Or baked chicken casserole.   They're 2 different results.

Comment: Actually I think you're right.  It could be argued my result set is wrong.  I should always have all 3.  I just need a value in style for it being on it's own.  Then sometimes cooking method is mentioned even though it's implicit but that's fine (eg pasta is always boiled, have one for uncooked/raw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I ended up using was to add a value for style that had the name 'none' (eg chicken can be just chicken but you'll never just eat ground beef on it's own no matter how you cook it.  Value actually makes sense to have).  Once I did that there was no need to show nulls.  Doing that made this way easier.

```
SELECT central_item.name as central_item_name, cooking_method.name as cooking_method_name, style.name as style_name FROM central_item
INNER JOIN central_item_style ON central_item_style.central_item = central_item.id
INNER JOIN style ON style.id = central_item_style.style
INNER JOIN cooking_method_style ON cooking_method_style.style = central_item_style.style
INNER JOIN cooking_method ON cooking_method.id = cooking_method_style.cooking_method
INNER JOIN central_item_cooking_method ON central_item_cooking_method.cooking_method = cooking_method_style.cooking_method AND central_item_cooking_method.central_item = central_item.id
GROUP BY central_item_name, cooking_method_name, style_name
ORDER BY central_item_name, cooking_method_name, style_name
```

Solution to the original question I asked in case anyone else needs it is this.  There might be a better way but this is the best I could come up with.

It basically unions a query for central_item/cooking_method pairs, central_item/style pairs and lastly central_item/cooking_method/style relationships.  Then I have to wrap the whole thing in another query because it generates a lot of garbage results (eg style_name and cooking_method_name are both null for many results).

I'm sure there's a better way to do this but it's beyond me.

```
SELECT central_item_name, cooking_method_name, style_name FROM
(SELECT central_item.name as central_item_name, null as cooking_method_name, null as style_name FROM central_item

UNION

SELECT central_item.name as central_item_name, cooking_method.name as cooking_method_name, null as style_name FROM cooking_method
INNER JOIN central_item_cooking_method ON central_item_cooking_method.cooking_method = cooking_method.id
INNER JOIN central_item ON central_item.id = central_item_cooking_method.central_item

UNION

SELECT central_item.name as central_item_name, null as cooking_method_name, style.name as style_name FROM style
INNER JOIN central_item_style ON central_item_style.style = style.id
INNER JOIN central_item ON central_item.id = central_item_style.central_item

UNION

SELECT central_item.name as central_item_name, cooking_method.name as cooking_method_name, style.name as style_name FROM central_item
INNER JOIN central_item_style ON central_item_style.central_item = central_item.id
INNER JOIN style ON style.id = central_item_style.style
INNER JOIN cooking_method_style ON cooking_method_style.style = central_item_style.style
INNER JOIN cooking_method ON cooking_method.id = cooking_method_style.cooking_method
INNER JOIN central_item_cooking_method ON central_item_cooking_method.cooking_method = cooking_method_style.cooking_method AND central_item_cooking_method.central_item = central_item.id


ORDER by central_item_name, cooking_method_name, style_name) iq
WHERE iq.cooking_method_name IS NOT NULL or iq.style_name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Steak tartare, anyone?

Comment: @Mark Can you explain why do you need the table `cooking_method_style` in this query? Because the only reason I can imagine is to eliminate the errors in bad quality data. But I see no sense to use it when your data is in good state.

Comment: I ended up reworking this because you're mostly right.  Now the first relationship is between central item, cooking method and style.  Then I look at the style only and find a related cooking method.  Eg central item: Steak, cooking_method: Barbecue, style: pizza, cooking_method (for the pizza): baked.  So I still need cooking_method_style to relate pizza and ways to cook it but the initial way I was doing this was wrong.  Probably better examples but that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example (but note that it returns a slightly different result set)...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ingredients;
 CREATE TABLE ingredients
 (ingredient_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,ingredient VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO ingredients VALUES (1    ,'Chicken'),(2    ,'Shrimp');

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS methods;
 CREATE TABLE methods
 (method_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,method VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO methods VALUES
 (1    ,'Bake'),
 (2    ,'Fry');

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS styles;
 CREATE TABLE styles
 (style_id   INT NOT NULL
 ,style VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO styles VALUES
 (1    ,'Casserole'),(2    ,'Pie');

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ingredient_method;
 CREATE TABLE ingredient_method
 (ingredient_id INT NOT NULL,method_id INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(ingredient_id,method_id));

 INSERT INTO ingredient_method VALUES
 (1             ,1),(1             ,2),(2             ,1),(2             ,2);

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ingredient_style;
 CREATE TABLE ingredient_style
 (ingredient_id INT NOT NULL,style_id INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(ingredient_id,style_id));

 INSERT INTO ingredient_style VALUES
 (1             ,1),(1             ,2),(2             ,1);


 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS method_style;

 CREATE TABLE method_style
 (method_id INT NOT NULL,style_id INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(method_id,style_id));

 INSERT INTO method_style VALUES(1               ,1),(2               ,2);


 SELECT i.ingredient
      , s.style
      , m.method
   FROM ingredients i
   LEFT
   JOIN ingredient_style si
     ON si.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id
   LEFT
   JOIN ingredient_method im
     ON im.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id   
   LEFT
   JOIN styles s
     ON s.style_id = si.style_id
   LEFT
   JOIN method_style ms
     ON ms.style_id = si.style_id
   LEFT
   JOIN methods m 
     ON m.method_id IN(ms.method_id,m.method_id = im.method_id);

+------------+-----------+--------+
| ingredient | style     | method |
+------------+-----------+--------+
| Chicken    | Casserole | Bake   |
| Chicken    | Casserole | Bake   |
| Chicken    | Casserole | Fry    |
| Chicken    | Pie       | Bake   |
| Chicken    | Pie       | Fry    |
| Chicken    | Pie       | Fry    |
| Shrimp     | Casserole | Bake   |
| Shrimp     | Casserole | Bake   |
| Shrimp     | Casserole | Fry    |
+------------+-----------+--------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0127/1

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    central_item.name central_item_name, 
    cooking_method.name cooking_method_name, 
    style.name style_name
from
    central_item ci
    left join (
        central_item_style cis
        join style s on cis.style = s.id
    ) on ci.id = cis.central_item
    left join (
        central_item_cooking_method cicm
        join cooking_method cm on cicm.cooking_method = cm.id
    ) on ci.id = cicm.central_item
```

Optional lines of code if your database has data integrity problems:

```
    left join cooking_method_style cms on 
        cms.style = cis.style and cms.cooking_method = cicm.cooking_method
where
    cms.style is not null
    or
    cis.style is null or cicm.cooking_method is null
```